# How to set AdSense Cookie after user approves cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, adsense

To implement AdSense code I have added following in between the html head tags as requested by AdSense:

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx" async
  src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

On page load adsense sets a cookie named .doubleclick.net.

I want the users to click on a button (approve cookies) before the cookie is set. **How would you code that in javascript?**

Since this needs to be in the head, I have no clue how to do this.

I am guessing this is not viable:

```
<head>
    <script>
        $('#Approve-Cookie').click(function(){
            <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>   
        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body></body>
```

Or maybe something like this?

```
$('#Approve-Cookie').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js",
      dataType: "script",
      async: true,
      success: callback,
      scriptAttrs: { data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx" }  
    });
}
```

But can't get the scriptAttrs to work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution to my own problem is following:

```
$('#Approve-Cookie').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js",
      dataType: "script",
      async: true,
      scriptAttrs: { "data-ad-client": "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx" }
    }); 
});
```